# Remove an element from std::list if a similar element is already present

Tags: c++, multithreading, list, class, stl

My list looks like:

```
list<event_t*> my_list;
```

Class event_t looks like:

```
class event_t {

public:
  event_t(String *_session_time, String *_event_type, String *_table_name, String *_num_of_events);
  ~event_t();
   std::string table_name;
   std::string event_type;  
   pthread_mutex_t lock;
   pthread_cond_t cond;
   int num_of_events_threshold;
   double time_out; 
   int num_of_events_so_far; 
};
```

I want to erase an event_t object if a similar object is already present in the list. I have a pointer to the object to be deleted. How do I erase it from the list? Two event_t objects are similar if they have same table_name and same event_type.

Comment: I don't see the need for a pointer.

Comment: are you talking about pointer in list?

Comment: Yes, it's completely unnecessary as far as I can tell.

Comment: I would appreciate some elaboration. I could need a list of pointers to do many things, which could be changing the number_of_events count.
If there is some kind of association with some other class, then we would definitely need pointers.

Answer (score 1):

in C++03 you might do it this way:

```
struct equal {
      bool operator()(const event_t* t) {
        return *t == object_;
      } 
      event_t object_;
      equal(event_t object) : object_(object) {}
};

  event_t object;
  list<event_t*>::iterator pend = my_list.remove_if (equal(object));
```

I assume you have defined `operator==` for your class `event_t`. If not then use this version:

```
struct equal {
          bool operator()(const event_t* t) {
            return t->table_name == object_.table_name
                               && t->event_type == object_.event_type;
          } 
          event_t object_;
          equal(event_t object) : object_(object) {}
    };
```

In C++0x (C++11) you can use lambda function as a predicate to `remove_if`.

```
event_t* object;

my_list.remove_if([object](event_t* e){ 
                  return e->table_name == toDelete->table_name 
                      && e->event_type == toDelete->event_type; 
                  });
```

As others replied: please rethink the idea of using pointers, it might be much better design to use a `list<event_t>` (if you don't really need pointers). Then you can just `std::list::sort` and use `std::list::unique` on it.

Comment: Better use container's interface instead generic functions. list.remove_if would be better.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `std::list::remove_if`.

```
event_t* toDelete;
// set toDelete
// Now remove all elements from the list that have the same table_name and event_type as toDelete
my_list.remove_if([toDelete](event_t* e){
                                 return e->table_name == toDelete->table_name &&
                                        e->event_type == toDelete->event_type; 
                                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and then use [unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: use a custom comparison predicate.

Comment: then remove_if might be faster

Comment: I missed the part about him already having a pointer to the element to be deleted. Hard to know what the best option is without a bit more context. Using a set with a custom comparison predicate might be the best choice depending on the wider context.